# Optimizing select union select oracle

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I had an interview recently and the recruiter told me to make a query on a table `USERS` with two fields (name, age) which should return a list with two columns `| NAME | MAJOR OR MINOR |`

My response was this :

```
(select NAME, 'MAGOR' as MAJ_MIN from USERS WHERE AGE >= 18 )
union
(select NAME, 'MINOR' as gender from USERS where AGE < 18);
```

Then, he told me that is correct, but we can do better!

So, my question is: How to do it in a better way?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: you can use case

Comment: The first improvement would be `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION [DISTINCT]`. But yes, selecting all rows using a `CASE` expression is still way better.

Comment: Your interviewer specified 'MAJOR' and you wrote 'MAGOR'... Also the brackets aren't needed, and as @ThorstenKettner said UNION ALL avoids the implicit DISTINCT that you get with UNION.

Comment: Their point is that `ALL` runs faster than the default of `DISTINCT`.

Comment: Another answer involves a "generated" column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume

```
select name, 
       case when age >= 18 then 'MAGOR' else 'MINOR' end maj_min
from users
```

Comment: Even fewer keystrokes if you use an `IF()`.

Comment: That may be, @Rick, but not in Oracle (that's one of tags the OP had used).